# Is there any way to calculate the system's CPU utilization as it is calculated in Task Manager using SQL Server queries?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, cpu, cpu-usage

I am using C# code to get the client's system information. There are situations which the client's database is on another server and it is not possible to access it using WMI. Therefore, I want to get the CPU utilization data using SQL Server queries as it is being represented in the system's Task Manager:

[image: Illustration screenshot]

Comment: So are you saying the other clients update the database with the information you seek and you now need to query it or what?

Comment: You can't do this, for the simple reason that SQL Server only grants access to its *own* CPU utilization, as a good citizen ought to do. As long as you are only interested in the CPU consumption of SQL Server itself (or it's the only significant process running on the machine, which would be the common case on a properly configured server), `sys.dm_os_performance_counters` would be of use (as well as other `dm_os_` views that contain CPU usage info, like `sys.dm_os_schedulers`).

Comment: "CPU utilization data using SQL Server queries" - What?